# Hive SQL query with empty table

Tags: hiveql

The problem is that when I run the query I got an empty table which is wrong base on the data I have, so is my logic wrong or I'm missing something?

Based on the provided tables write a query in HIV SQL to answer question 1

**employees** ( employee_num , last_name , first_name , status , hire_date , last_date_worked , job_title , job_code , home_branch )

**transactions** ( branch_num , contract_num , customer_num , invoice_date ,invoice_num , product_num , sales_amount , employee_num , service_date , system_period )

**Question 1:**

> Show the employees who serviced customers before 1/1/2005. Employee
>   names must be concatenated to produce this format: LastName,
>   FirstName. For example, “Doe, John”. The result should have two
>   columns: employee name and service date.

**My answer:**

```
SELECT concat(e.first_name, ', ', e.last_name) AS employee_name, t.service_date FROM employees e 
FULL OUTER JOIN transactions t
ON    e.employee_num = t.employee_num WHERE t.service_date < '1/1/2005';
```

Comment: According to https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/customers-customernum-int-branchnum-int-address1-string-address2-string-city-string-state--q36012042 service_date is a string... does `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE service_date < '1/1/2005'` return anything?

Comment: yes, its string. no, it returns nothing which is not right